# Crop image and place it in image view in android

Tags: android

My aim is to set a circular profile pic for my app.User can crop the image and place it as profile pic. my code can crop the pic but unable to place it in the image view.Please Help !!!
Please find the code below:

```
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,SELECT_PICTURE_PROFILE);
}

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent, Intent data) {

                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

                switch (requestCode) {
                    case SELECT_PICTURE_PROFILE:
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                            if (imageReturnedIntent!=null) {
                                Bundle extras = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
                                Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");

                                BitmapDrawable bd=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), selectedBitmap);
                                imageViewRound = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cimgv1);
                                imageViewRound.setImageDrawable(bd);

                            }
                        }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {


        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        //Bitmap _bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 60, 60, false);
        //return _bmp;
        return output;
    }
```

use this function to get cropped Image.

Comment: for me it's working like a Charm :D                                                                                    im_user.setImageBitmap(Utility.getCroppedBitmap(loadedImage));

Comment: Can u help me on how to store the image user cropped in the mobile's  gallery?